# Can't get SVG Style CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I get the SVG Data `svgData` as String from the server.

This returns (for the example .svg I am working with) 62 pathes:

```
var svgPath = $(svgData).find('[class*="style"]');
```

With the following code I am recalculating the stroke-size of the SVG:

```
for (var i = 0; i < svgPath.length; ++i) {
  oldStrokeWidth.push(jQuery(svgPath[i]).css('stroke-width').replace(/[^-\d.]/g, ''));
  var newStrokeWidth = oldStrokeWidth[i] * 1.1;

  jQuery(svgPath[i]).css(
    'stroke-width', newStrokeWidth
  );

  oldStrokeWidth[i] = newStrokeWidth;
}
```

In the `oldStrokeWidth` Array are no 62 zeros.

I traced the error to this part

```
jQuery(svgPath[i]).css('stroke-width')
```

It delivers `""` for every path.

If I manually add `jQuery(svgPath[i]).css('stroke-width', 50)` and check again i get the correct `"50px"` answer. So I it looks like it is empty and doesn't contain a value. When working I expect 0.5 or the pixel value as an answer.

Here is the style part of the SVG:

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
   .normal {
     stroke: black
   }
  .dimension {
    stroke: green
   }
  .cosmetic {
    stroke: blue
   }
  .centerLine {
    stroke: red
   }
  .style0 {
     stroke-width: 0.5
   }
  .style1 {
     stroke-width: 0.35
   }
 .style2 {
     stroke-width: 0.35; stroke-opacity: 0.2;
   stroke-dasharray: 2,1
 }
.style3 {
   stroke-width: 0.35;
   stroke-dasharray: 0.4,1,2,1
}
.style10 {
   stroke-width: 0.35;
   stroke-dasharray: 2,1
}
]]></style>
</defs>
 </svg>
```

Maybe someone knows why this happens.

Comment: `svgPath` is already a jQuery object. You should only need to do: `svgPath[i].css('stroke-width')`

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can see the issue in action for ourselves.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Unfortunately this isn't the reason. I tried it before. too. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Reading the `stroke-width` works for me (https://jsfiddle.net/5y9v5uy5/5/). There must be something else going on. Maybe we can help if you post a [mcve].

Comment: I'll try to do later, but i don't really know how to make it simple AND like it works in my code just in JSFiddle or so, cause it's a more complex code. but I'll give it a look later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting "" from .css("stroke-width"), the chained replace will also return an "".

Therefore the only way you are ending up with NaN in your oldStrokeWidth array is that this._svgZoomFactor is undefined. What happens is:

"" is converted to 0, if 'this' is not referring to the correct object then you will end up getting  this._svgZoomFactor being undefined. And undefined * "" will evaluate to NaN.

Check that 'this' is referring to your constructor.

EDIT: I think you have not provided whether you are doing DOM operations on an SVG that is part of the document tree or not. Jquery .css will internally use getComputedStyle and that will return "" if svg is not yet appended. But when you are setting the style, it will instead set the style attribute individually on the elements which explains why you get "" in the first place but you can set it later.

Comment: So, thanks, that was the first problem. `this._svgZoomFactor` was undefined. Now I end up with 62 zeros

Comment: You can try a couple of things: 1- add px to the style declarations like 0.5px. 2 - Try removing the inline style and load it as an external stylesheet in a link tag. Does that make a difference? (Not suggesting it as a solution, only to see if the problem is elsewhere)

Comment: The first on is not an option cause of server side generated images. If i can't find a solution, soon, I'll go and ask the backend guys to change it. The second solution mad no difference.

Comment: Hmm, for the first option did you remove the <![CDATA ..<]] before putting in the link tag? 2- You select paths starting with style, but can you confirm that each path element actually has a class like style0 or style1 etc.? 3-  This should not make a difference but does changing for instance .style0 to path.style0 do any good? 4- can you open the inspect element and see if the style within the defs is really there. If all data is coming from the server, and there is a parsing error due to the XML parsing (like the ! mark before the CDATA), it might be that the style is not parsed correctly

Comment: I am starting to think this is due to the CDATA itself. For instance: `var u = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(`<style><![CDATA[
  _......some style_
]]></style>`,"application/xml")`   will generate a style with CDATA still remaining (which is normal and the browser should normally still parse). Changing the mime type to "text/html" won't change it either. I recommend getting the style textContent and comment out the CDATA like /*<![CDATA[*/ and /*]]>*/. Then do defs.replaceChild(u.head.firstChild,defs.firstChild). Does this help?

Comment: AND most importantly, you have not provided the most crucial information: is the svg part of your document, is it appended yet??? Because if not, it is natural that you will get "" as stroke-width. The styles whether inline or not will not be applied if the svg is not rendered yet by the browser. You will always get "" unless you individually set style attribute on the path elements. If the svg is rendered, than try getComputedStyle(node).strokeWidth to see if it is defined.

Comment: You are my man. Thanks. Yeah the problem was the svg not rendered yet cause it is going to be drawn on a canvas and exists therefore only as a bitmap. To get the css I would have to draw it first. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem:) Good luck!